# Facebook likes is not displaying

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

So i'm curious to know how to write some code to make the Facebook "Likes" appear on the users timeline, activity feed and in their "Liked pages section". As of today im using the following code:

```
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="APP_ID" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://MY_URL.SE/" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://MY_URL.SE/med/fbLike.png" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="SITE_TITLE" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="SITE_NAME" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="DESCRIPTION" />
```

And the javascript for the Facebook Like button:

```
    var fbAppId = 'APP_ID';
    var objectToLike = 'https://MY_URL.SE';

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : APP_ID,
          status     : true,           
          cookie     : true,           
          xfbml      : true            
        });
    };

    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/sv_SE/all.js#xfbml=1";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    function postLike() {
        FB.api(
           'https://graph.facebook.com/me/og.likes',
           'post',
           { object: objectToLike,
             privacy: {'value': 'SELF'} },
           function(response) {
             if (!response) {
               alert('Error occurred.');
             } else if (response.error) {
               document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Error: ' + response.error.message;
             } else {
               document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =
                 '<a href=\"https://www.facebook.com/me/activity/' + response.id + '\" />';
             }
           }
        );
    }
```

The like counter is increasing/decreasing as intended but nothing is being displayed on Facebook. The debugger tool finds all the OG objects and doesn't report any errors. The app  is live and sandbox mode is deactivated, the Feed Dialog is working as intended (using the same app).

So why isn't it sharing the likes on the timeline/activity feed? Did i miss something?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried going to your facebook profile and clicking on the "activity log"  It lists all your activity whether its shared on your timeline or not.  I've found on a site I'm currently working on that the activity is shown there and in order to get it on my timeline I have to select that from the drop down next to the post in the activity log.